# Find $N \gt 0$ so that $ n \ge N \implies \lvert \left(1+\frac3n \right)^2 -1\rvert \lt \frac{1}{10}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, epsilon-delta

Here's the problem:

Find $N \gt 0$ so that

$$ n \ge N \implies \left\lvert \left(1+\frac3n \right)^2 -1\right\rvert \lt \frac{1}{10}$$

So, I'm not quite sure what this is asking me. I found a value of $n$ (e.g. $100$ works) that makes the consequent true, but I don't think that simply choosing any value for $N$ less than or equal to $100$ to make the antecedent true solves the problem. As in I don't see how the antecedent would *imply* the consequent in that case; it'd just be vacuously true if both propositions were true. Or am I going about this all wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You must find $N$, then for $N$ fixed you see that if $n>N$ the conclusion is true. Now, see @dragon anwser, this gives that for $N=62$ (for example) the inequality holds, now you must prove that the expresion $(1+3/n)^2-1$ is decreasing to complete the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $m = 1+\dfrac{3}{n} \to |m^2-1| < \dfrac{1}{10} \to -\dfrac{1}{10} < m^2-1 < \dfrac{1}{10} \to \dfrac{9}{10} < m^2 < \dfrac{11}{10} \to \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}} < m < \dfrac{\sqrt{11}}{\sqrt{10}}$. Observe that $\forall n \geq 1 \to m = 1+\dfrac{3}{n} > \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$. And $m < \dfrac{\sqrt{11}}{\sqrt{10}} \to \dfrac{3}{n} < \dfrac{\sqrt{11}-\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{10}}\to n > \dfrac{3\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{11}-\sqrt{10}}=3\sqrt{110}+30\approx 61.5$. Thus $N = 62$ or higher.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align*}\left\lvert \left(1+\frac3n \right)^2 -1\right\rvert \lt \frac{1}{10} &\iff -\frac{1}{10} \lt \left(1+\frac3n \right)^2-1 \lt \frac{1}{10}\\& \iff \frac{9}{10} \lt \left(1+\frac3n \right)^2 \lt \frac{11}{10} \\& \iff \sqrt{\frac{9}{10}} \lt 1+\frac3n \lt \sqrt{\frac{11}{10}} \\& \iff \sqrt{\frac{9}{10}}-1 \lt \frac3n \lt \sqrt{\frac{11}{10}}-1 \\& \implies  \frac n3 \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{11}{10}}-1} \\&\implies n \gt \frac{3}{\sqrt{\frac{11}{10}}-1}\end{align*}$$ so $n$ has to be at least $$n \ge \left \lceil \frac{3}{\sqrt{\frac{11}{10}}-1} \right \rceil= \lceil 61.46 \rceil =62$$

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{\frac{9}{10}}-1\lt 0$.

Comment: From the fourth line you can't dedude the fith line, due to $\sqrt{9/10}-1<0$. Moreover, see what you "proved" in the last line, you are saying that the inequality holds if and only if $A_1>n>A_2$ for some values of $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Comment: @mathlove. Yes, how silly. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @MrSelberg You are of course correct in your first correction and therefore perhaps in your second ("Moreover..." onwards) which I however do not understand. Thanks for noticing my silly mistake anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following equal to each other, that is,
$$\left\lvert \left(1+\frac3N \right)^2 -1\right\rvert = \frac{1}{10}$$
You will find that $N \approx 61.4643$.